Gamma distribution tricky problem
Suppose that the time, in hours, it takes to repair a pump is a random variable X
which has a gamma distribution with parameters α = 2, β = 1/2.
what is the probability that
a. it takes at most 1 hour to repair the pump?
b. Will it take at least 2 hours to repair the pump?
c. it takes between 1 and 2 hours
now I was trying using the gamma integral tables:
$$P(X\leq 1) = 0.59$$
$$P(X\geq 2) = 0.091$$
then:
$$P(1\leq X \leq2) = 0.091 - 0.59 = -0.49$$
my problem is that the last probability is negative am I using the tables in the wrong way? whats going on

are you using $P(X\le 2)$ or $P(X\ge 2)$ ?

@SineoftheTime $P(X>= 2)$

see @heropup's answer

@SineoftheTime i get the $P(X <= 2)$ but not the $P(X <= 1)$

Well, the first thing is that you've confused $\Pr[X \ge 2]$ with $\Pr[X \le 2]$.  You have to write $$\Pr[1 \le X \le 2] = \Pr[X \le 2] - \Pr[X < 1] = (1 - \Pr[X > 2]) - \Pr[X < 1].$$

The second issue, which is relatively minor, is that you should specify whether the gamma distribution is parametrized by shape and rate, or by shape and scale.  What I mean by this is that a shape/rate parametrization means
$$f_X(x) = \frac{\beta^\alpha x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)},$$
whereas a shape/rate parametrization means
$$f_X(x) = \frac{x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x/\beta}}{\beta^\alpha \Gamma(\alpha)}.$$
Based on the numerical values you provided, I believe you intend $\beta$ to be a scale parameter.  In such a case,
$$\Pr[X \le 1] \approx 0.593994,$$
and
$$\Pr[X \ge 2] \approx 0.0915782.$$
These are the answers to the first two parts of your question.  The answer to the third part is as I described above:  this is because the probability that it takes between $1$ and $2$ hours to repair the pump must be equal to the probability that it takes two hours or less to repair the pump, minus the probability that it takes less than one hour to repair the pump.  Since $X$ is a continuous random variable, $\Pr[X > 2] = \Pr[X \ge 2]$ and $\Pr[X < 1] = \Pr[X \le 1]$.

why are you using $P[X <= 2]$

do you think my first two answers are correct?

"Between 1 and 2 hours" means "more than 1 hour but less than 2." "At least 2 hours" means "more than 2."

ohh I see , do you think the logic is good in the first two questions?

in the last question why not $P(x <= 2) - P(X >= 1)$

I don´t understand why

@samsamradas The integral ignores $<$ versus $\leq.$ It has been explained in the edit.

@samsamradas Suppose $0 \le X \le 2$.  Then either $0 \le X \le 1$, or $1 < X \le 2$.  For instance, pick a number between $0$ and $2$.  Then this number must either be between $0$ and $1$, or between $1$ and $2$.  Do you agree?  Furthermore, there is no "overlap" between the intervals $[0,1]$ and $(1,2]$.  So $$\Pr[X \le 2] = \Pr[X \le 1] + \Pr[1 < X \le 2].$$  Now rearrange:  $$\Pr[1 < X \le 2] = \Pr[X \le 2] - \Pr[X \le 1].$$
